# toggle background color of the button not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to toggle the background colour of the button as like changing the margin, for some reason margin works and `btn` colour doesn't.

```
<script>
   let myBtn = document.querySelector("#menuBtn");

   function myFunction1() {
    var Menubase = document.getElementById("list-menu-base");
    if (Menubase.style.marginTop==="0px") {
    Menubase.style.marginTop="-250px";
    } else {
    Menubase.style.marginTop="0px";
      }
    }

myBtn.onclick = myFunction1;

   // The above function works bu not the one follows// 

   function myFunction3() {
  var Menubase = document.getElementById("menuBtn");
  if (Menubase.style.backgroundColor==="red") {
    Menubase.style.backgroundColor="#FF7E00";
  } else {
    Menubase.style.backgroundColor="#FF7E00";
  }
}

myBtn.onclick = myFunction3;
</script>
```

Comment: You're setting the color every time to `#FF7E00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of your code inside each function.

You can't have two `onClick` Events for the same element.

Wrap your two functions with one container function like:

```
function fullFunction() { 
   myFunction1();
   myFunction3();
}
myBtn.onclick = fullFunction;
```

Second: 
You should add the color in `rgb` on your javascript code instead of `hex`.

Demo:

```js
let myBtn = document.querySelector("#menuBtn");

function myFunction1() {
  var Menubase = document.getElementById("list-menu-base");
  if (Menubase.style.marginTop === "0px") {
    Menubase.style.marginTop = "25px";
  } else {
    Menubase.style.marginTop = "0px";
  }
}

function myFunction3() {
  var myBtn = document.getElementById("menuBtn");
  if (myBtn.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(142, 253, 27)") {
    myBtn.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 103, 0)";
  } else {
    myBtn.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(142, 253, 27)";
  }
}

function fullFunction() {
  myFunction1();
  myFunction3();
}
myBtn.onclick = fullFunction;
```

```css
#menuBtn {
  background-color: rgb(255, 103, 0);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#list-menu-base {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-menu-base"></div>
<a id="menuBtn" href="#">MENU BUTTON</a>
```

Comment: Then there is a problem with your code. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Even as a single function the css change of background color doesn't work...! could you pls check that out?

Comment: function myFunction3() {
 
  if (myBtn.style.backgroundColor=== "rgb(255,126,0)") {
    myBtn.style.backgroundColor= "rgb(255,226,0)";
  }else{
    myBtn.style.backgroundColor= "rgb(255,126,0)";
  }
}

myBtn.onclick = myFunction3;

Comment: basically, I need to toggle the color of the button and the as follows

Comment: <a id="menuBtn" href="#">MENU BUTTON</a>

Comment: css :  #menuBtn{
 background-color:#FF6700;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 100px;
}

Comment: // javascript//   function myFunction3() {
 
  if (myBtn.style.backgroundColor=== "#8EFD1B") {
    myBtn.style.backgroundColor= "#FF6700";
  }else{
    myBtn.style.backgroundColor= "#8EFD1B";
  }
}

myBtn.onclick = myFunction3;

Comment: I've Updated the Answer

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate...!

Answer (score 0):

You need fix your js

```
function myFunction3() {
    var Menubase = document.getElementById("menuBtn");
    // Don't exists red color, so u can try use the rgb
    if (Menubase.css('color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
        Menubase.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,126,0)";
    } else {
        Menubase.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,126,100)";
    }
}
```